# New type that is the union of the values of every key on a parent type

Tags: typescript

So I want to generate a type, that is the union of all possible values using all possible keys on a combination of types.  Hard to word this, so best to show it.

So here is my example

```
type A = {
  page: string,
  other: number,
}

type B = {
  obj: {
    something: string
  }
  page: string,
}

export type AllViews = {
  a: A;
  b: B;
};

export type View = keyof AllViews;

type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type AllTypes = AllViews[View];
type AllTypeKeys = KeysOfUnion<AllTypes>;
```

You can see that `AllTypes`, is a union of my two types A and B
[image]

And my `AllTypeKeys` is the union of every possible key between the two types.
[image]

So here is where my problem lies.  I want a new type, that is every possible value for all keys of both objects.  In this case the type should be `string | number | { something: string }`

The only way I can think to do this currently, is very manually.

```
type AType = AllViews['a'];
type AKeyType = keyof AllViews['a'];
type AValueType = AType[AKeyType];

type BType = AllViews['b'];
type BKeyType = keyof AllViews['b'];
type BValueType = BType[BKeyType];

type AllValues = AValueType | BValueType;
```

My end result is this.
[image]

My code will eventually have dozens of these new types on the parent type, and I would hate to have to keep manually adding this for every new key/value I add.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question, all you would need to do is create a single generic type:

```js
  type All<T> = T[keyof T]
```

and then use that with the conjunction of your existing types, e.g.

```js
type AllValues = All<A&B> // string | number | { something: string }
```

[Update in response to comment]:

To not have to explicitly list the `A&B` part requires an additional generic type:

```js
type All2<T> = {[K in keyof T]: All<T[K]>}; // I suck at naming things
type AllValues = All<All2<AllViews>>; // string | number | { something: string }
```

Comment: So that is really close, thank you for this.  The missing is someone auto generating the `A&B` from the `AllViews` type.  So anytime I add a new key to `AllViews`, this new `AllValues` automatically gets it without having to update that line of code.